# Under what conditions can [NSEvent characters] be a NSString of length greater than 1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsevent

NSEvent has a characters property which is a NSString valid for key up/down events. Under what conditions can the string length be greater than 1?

The only condition I have been able to find till now is when the NSEvent corresponds to input from an IME (Input Method Editor).

Edit - I knew about the surrogate pair case, but it somehow slipped out of my mind while asking this. I am more interested in the case when the no. of graphemes(characters) is greater than 1 itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also get this with programmatically-posted events. `CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString()` allows the caller to attach any arbitrary string to the key event.

Answer (score 1):

> Under what conditions can the string length be greater than 1?

When you have a keyboard/input method which can input any single character which requires a surrogate pair in UTF-16, e.g. a  (Unicode Linear B Syllable B008 A), then the `length` will be 2. This is because `length` returns the number of 16-bit code units, not the number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

High unicode codepoints are coded with a character sequence in Mac OS X. Try .